# Regression with many discrete and continuous predictors and few rows

Tags: statistics, regression

I want to do regression on a dataset. It has one continuous dependent variable that I want to predict. It has many categorical and some continuous predictors. It only has a few rows.

A simplified example might look like this (Dx means discrete predictor, Cx means continuous predictor, IV is the independent variable I'm trying to predict.):

```
+----+-------+---------+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+
| IV |  D1   |   D2    | D3  |   D4    |   D5    | C1  | C2  |
+----+-------+---------+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+
|  5 | 1,2,3 | 1,2     | 1   | 1       | 1       | 2   | 3.5 |
|  4 | 2,3,4 | 1,3     | 2   | 2,3     | 1,2     | 2.5 | -2  |
| -2 | 1,3,5 | 2,3     | 3,4 | 2       | 1,3     | 2.2 | 50  |
|  4 | 4,6,7 | 4,5,6,7 | 4,5 | 3,4,5,6 | 1,2,3,4 | 2.2 | 50  |
+----+-------+---------+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+
```

You can see that the categorical variables can have multiple discrete values for each row, so I can dummy code it like this to simplify the data:

```
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
| IV | D1-1 | D1-2 | D1-3 | D1-4 | D1-5 | D1-6 | D1-7 | ... |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|  5 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | ... |
|  4 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 | ... |
| -2 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 | ... |
|  4 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 | ... |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

Now the key is: I can't do multiple linear regression because the number of rows is less than the number of columns, and I don't want to remove any of the predictors.

One way (Method A) I thought could work is to do individual linear regression for each predictor and combine the linear models into one. However I don't really know how to combine them. One possible way is to use the correlation coefficient (r^2/sum of all r^2) as the weight for each predictor, but I don't know whether there's a better way.

Another way (Method B) - I feel is better - is to use individual linear regression for the continuous variables, and just a mean/variance analysis for the discrete variables (like ANOVA), then combine the models using the some transform of the standard variation f(sigma) as the weight for each discrete variable, and f(r^2) as the weight for the continuous variable.

Therefore, my questions are:

1. If I use method B, what should be the f(sigma) and f(r^2)? (How should I combine the individual models?)
2. Is there a better way?

Comment: Should be asked in [Cross Validated] (http://stats.stackexchange.com/). And I think regression cant work because number of rows less then the number of predictors.

Comment: @SAAN I've posted on cross validated but no one is answering the question there. Also I'm aware that multiple regression will not work unless dimensions are reduced, which is why I'm asking for a model mixing mechanism.

Comment: 2. Have you considered to combine some independent variable? Like, if some set of them, say D1-D5, measuring correlated variables, you can try to add them up into one variable. It may also solve possible multicollinearity problems that may arise in data like this.